# Comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast

Tags: iphone

this is my code

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.tableDataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSArray *Children = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Children"];
    NSArray *Title = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];

if([Children count] == 0) {
    if(Title =="A #1"){
UIImageView *tmp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg2.png"]]; 
        [dvController.detailImage addSubview:tmp]; 
        [tmp release];
```

}
i am not able to compare "Title", `at if(Title == "A #1") ,` its giving warning `"Compariosn of distinct pointer types lacks a cast"`  how can i compare Title in if condition.
i also tried

```
if([Title isequalToString:@"A #1"])...but its not working for me.
```

Sry for unformated question.
regards

Comment: Please take care of your formatting before posting. There is a preview. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your data structure looks weird... what do you want to store in that dictionary?**

But as others already said: if `Title` is of `NSArray` you won't get true when compared to a string or `NSString`.

If `Title` should be of `NSString` you might call this:

```
NSString *title = [dict objectForKey:@"Title"];
if ([title isEqualToString:@"my string"]) { /* do it */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

You declared Title as an NSArray*, so it's obviously a different type from a string and can't be compared to a string.  (Perhaps this is a typo?)

Perhaps something more like:

```
NSString myTitleString = (NSString *)[dictionary stringForKey"@"Title"]

if ( [ myTitleString isEqualToString:@"foo") ] ) { ... }
```

is what you want?

Comment: Thanks
i tried ur code also, but on declaring it to NSstring, warning comes, up with, "NSdictonary may not respond -stringFor Key"...wat do u suggest now?

Comment: Oops. You need to get the NSArray from the NSDictionary, and the NSString from the NSArray.  My code skips a step there.  Can you figure that out and insert the missing step?  Or do you need code?

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *Title = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];
```

Title is type of `NSArray`  and "A #1" is `NSString` Compiler is 100% correct as always... you can't compare this two object because they are of distinct type

you might want something like

```
if([[Title objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"A #1"]])
```

OR

```
NSString  *Title = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];
if([Title isEqualToString:@"A #1"]])
```

Comment: It's not even NSString... it misses a @.

Comment: Thank for reply...but i tried ur snippet..app gets crashed...saying
" *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6f22760'"

Comment: then that title is not NSArray at all... Or it doesn't contain NSString...i can not tell what is your problem unless i know what you're storing for Title key in your dictionary..

Comment: this worked

"NSString title = [dict objectForKey:@"Title"];
if ([title isEqualToString:@"my string"]) { /* do it */ }"

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the code, which is a bit hard because of the formatting. You are defining Title as NSArray. If you want to make a string comparison you need an NSString. So you are either declaring "Title" of the wrong type, or you are expecting another array from the dictionary where you have your strings. I would assume it's the first. This should work:

```
NSString *titleString = [dictionary objectForKey"@"Title"];

if([titleString isEqualToString:@"A #1"]){
}
```